# jquery lightbox previous and next buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I´ve been looking at the jquery lightbox plugin and it seems simple enough, however i was wondering if there is anyway that i could make the plugin´s "previous" and "next" buttons work without the images being named sequentially (eg. "image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg"). Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

*Note: The images its working with are uploaded by users and are renamed to a random name generated by my php code during upload*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery lightbox does not rename images. If the images are named image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg, it is because they are named that way by the server or the uploader.

Comment: The images are renamed by my php code when the users upload the images but they are not named in the format "image1.jpg, image2.jpg, etc" the sample that comes with the lightbox plugin uses images with those names and if renamed the image doesnt load properly nor does it work with the previous and next buttons this is what im referring too

Comment: Could you atleast give us a sample of the code? I am personally using jQuery lightbox and I don't have a problem with filenames. It is possible that one of your filenames are messing up with the HTML mark-up

Comment: The sample code that comes with the plugin, if you go into the image directory and rename "image2.jpg" to "image2blah.jpg" and execute "index.htm" then select "image3.jpg" then hit previous it will not load the image due to the new file name...

Comment: That's because you did not update the `image` tag's `src` attribute. Or did you?

Comment: The src is change and the thumbnail image name is also changed to match. You can see the thumbnail image but when you want to see the full sized image it wont display. All you see is the loading image

Comment: Did you also change the `href` of the `a` tag?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3287/discussion-between-rolando-cruz-and-lord-link)

Comment: I forgot to change the href i completely overlooked that! Thanks a bunch! :)